# How to add supervisor name and university logo in the front page of thesis?

Tags: overleaf, templates, thesis

I have written my PhD thesis. But I am confused about the `\documentclass[..]{style}`, especially the front page of the thesis. I ma trying with the following templates:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
%\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\title{Thesis Title}
\author{submitted by \\ Author Name}
\date{date}
\titlehead{A Thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy}
\publishers{School of Something\\University of Somewhere}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter


\chapter{Acknowledgements}
I would like to thank my supervisor, Professor Someone. This
research was funded by the some Research Council.
\chapter{Abstract}
A brief summary of the project goes here.
% A glossary and list of acronyms may go here
% or may go in the back matter.
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}

\backmatter
% A glossary and list of acronyms may go here
% or may go in the front matter after the abstract.
% The bibliography will go here
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

If you run it, the front page looks like this:

[image]

> How do I add the supervisor's name just below the author's name? How do I add the university logo just above the university name?

To include university logo, we need to use `\usepackage{graphicx}`, but I am not sure how to incorporate it.

Comment: Instead of using `\maketitle` I'd use the `titlepage` and then style it all by hand. Then it is a lot easier to match the requirement that you are given.

Comment: @daleif, do you mean `\begin{titlepage}...frontpage material...\end{titlepage}` instead of `\maketitle` ?  Can you show a demo ?

Comment: The first stop is to look up the source for \maketitle from scrbook.cls.  The file location depends on your installation.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I have managed to do it according to my requirements.

Comment: @JohnKormylo,  I am facing one problem. When using `\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}` instead of `\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}`, there are some blank pages appearing after the acknowledgement chapter and abstract chapter. How to avoid such blank pages ?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I used `\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage` and the blank pages automatically gone

Comment: Note that `\maketitle` changes with each document class.  So what works for one class may not work for another.  Redefining `\cleardoublepage` seems overkill.